# Rails presence validation didn't working in params key as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, strong-parameters

I got this problem where my test fails because the validation presence: true didn't work. I wonder why it didn't trigger. So, here's the code that I have:

A simple update in controller

```
def update
   person = Person.find_by( params[:id] )

   if person.update( params_person )
      render json: {}, status: :ok
   else
      render json: person.errors, status: :422
   end
end

def params_person
  params.require( :person ).permit( :firstname, :lastname, ... , hobbies: [] )
end
```

The `hobbies: []` is an array of strings hobbies like `['playing dota', 'basketball', 'coding', ... ]`

Person model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :hobbies, presence: true
  ...
end
```

if I did a request which

```
{ ...
  ...
  hobbies: nil/'',
  ...
  ...
}
```

the validation still passing without update hobbies as the data `nil/''`

## Updated

```
describe '#update' do
    let( :user ) { create( :user ) }

    fcontext 'when params missing' do
      before do
        put :update, id: person.id,
            person: {
              ....,
              ....,
              hobbies: nil 
            }
      end

      it 'respond an error message' do
        expect( response_body ).to include( "Hobbies can't be blank" )
      end

      it { expect( response ).to have_http_status( 422 ) }
    end
```

Comment: Can you post your test?

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII post updated .. Thanks!

Comment: You are sending user { } in the test but the controller uses person.

Comment: sorry. I modify it should be person  @eagleeye.

Answer (score 1):

When you put `hobbies: []` in strong_params definition and then proceed to pass a scalar to `hobbies` (your `nil` there), it won't be permitted by strong params and, therefore, will not be touched in an update.

To verify this, inspect `params_person` in that test.

Comment: but how about empty string why it act the same thing?

Comment: @PepengA.: because it's a scalar too.

Comment: So, how can I trigger the validation? should I create a custom validator to check whether the hobbies array got a value or not?

Comment: @PepengA.: try passing empty array

Comment: I did already but still it didn't trigger the validation. That's why I don't know how I can validate it.

Comment: @PepengA. What's the value of `params_person` when you pass an empty array?

Comment: `{"id"=>"1", "person"=>{ ... , ... , "hobbies"=>[]}, "controller"=>"person", "action"=>"update"}` -- this is the params

Comment: @PepengA.: well, I'm out of ideas. Some debugging is needed here.